# Magento : How to track or best way of tracking a customer session?

Tags: php, magento, session

Currently I'm working on a Magento module that allows customers to upload files against their order at the product page.

So what I thought was to have the files saved in a folder created with the session id as the folder name, until they submit their order. But then I ran in to an issue with this solution, which is, when a customer uploads a file as a guest and if they logged in after, or if they create a new account, the session ID get change, and no way of back tracking previous session data or id.

I looked at visitor ID and that doesn't work either. coz for a new customers/visitors don't have a visitor id, so thats out too.

Any suggestion?

Comment: I would like to have comments from whoever down voted my question, Please tell me the reason for down voting, so I can improve my question. Do not down-vote just because you can do it.

Comment: I would simple force the login, then store them by `customer_id` instead. It's far more reliable.

Comment: But the user experience wont be that good. Because this file upload is going to be a Photo upload that allows customers to personalise what they are about to buy. So people who just come in to the web site would like to play around with it. and see how it looks. If we force login that would be ok for a existing customer but not for a new one I reckon.

Comment: It's a valid question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visitor ID doesn't change after login. It changes after logout, which is perfectly normal. Also, all visitors have visitor ID, whether they new or not or logged in or not.

Comment: Yep, I re-did some testing and went through Mage_Log_Model_Visitor and  Mage_Log_Model_Resource_Visitor, its looks like visitor ID doesn't get changed and available for new visitors too. So going ahead in this path

Answer (score 1):

You can track such instances with a cookie & the right expiry time. The following documentation helped me out a lot when working with cookies:

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html